# Property of Matrix Inverse / Matrix Inverse Derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-equations

I am given real, symmetric matrices $X \succ B \succ A \succ 0$ (where '$\succ$' signifies positive definiteness such that if $B \succ A$ then $B-A \succ 0$ is positive definite). Further let the '$\preceq$' operator signify negative semi-definiteness (and $\succeq$ signify positive semi-definiteness). Does the following hold?
\begin{align}
(X + B)^{-1} - (X + B + A)^{-1} + (2B + 2A)^{-1} - (2B)^{-1} \preceq 0
\end{align}
A few observations:

1. As the inverse is operator decreasing I know that:
   \begin{align}
    (2B + 2A)^{-1} - (2B)^{-1} \preceq 0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\mbox{and}\;\;\;\;\;\; (X + B)^{-1} - (X + B + A)^{-1} \succeq 0.
   \end{align}
2. If $A = I$, $B = 2I$, $X = 3I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, the above inequality holds.
3. I believe the derivative of the matrix inverse should play a role here. Essentially, how does the addition of $A$ (or $2A$) affect the negative semi-definiteness of the above expression when (i) adding $A$ to $X+B$ (in the inverse) makes the expression more positive semi-definite and (ii) adding $2A$ to $2B$ (in the inverse) makes the expression more negative semi-definite. If the matrix inverse is somehow 'negative', then adding $2A$ should make the expression more negative semi-definite than adding $A$.

Thank you very much for any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to generate a random counterexample by computer, e.g.
$$
X=I,\ B=\pmatrix{0.9&0\\ 0&0.1},\ A=\pmatrix{0.7&0.07\\ 0.07&0.01}.
$$
Numerical computation shows that the eigenvalues of $C=(X + B)^{-1} - (X + B + A)^{-1} + (2B + 2A)^{-1} - (2B)^{-1}$ are approximately $0.007$ and $-0.418$. Therefore $C$ is indefinite.

Comment: But A is not positive definite, the eigenvalues are roughly -0.065 and 0.6165.

Comment: @OttoVonBismarck I didn't notice the requirement that $A\succ0$ before. It's fixed now.

Comment: Alas, this does break the inequality. I still wish I had more insight! Do you know if there's an example where the inequality also doesn't hold when $X \succ B \succ A \succ I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: @OttoVonBismarck If you scale $X,B$ and $A$ by the same factor $\alpha>0$, then when $\alpha$ is sufficiently large, $A$ will eventually be $\succ I$. Since the new $C$ is just $\frac1\alpha$ times the old $C$, it is still indefinite and your inequality still doesn't hold.

Comment: Ah yes yes, good. Thank you very much!